# Issue getting closures to work

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a piece of code that I'm trying to have alert `1,2,3`.  I'm having issues using closures properly, so I can't figure this out.

The original code:

```
function buildList(list) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var item = 'item' + list[i];
        result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])} );
    }
    return result;
}

function testList() {
    var fnlist = buildList([1,2,3]);
    // using j only to help prevent confusion - could use i
    for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
        fnlist[j]();
    }
}

testList();
```

I am trying to do something like this to `buildList()` to get it to work properly:

```
function buildList(list) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var item = 'item' + list[i];
        result[i] = function(x) {
            result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[x])} );   
        }(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I know I'm making mistakes on working with the closures, I'm just not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second try was closer to the solution but still doesn't work because your inner-most function is capturing variable `item` from your top-level function: `item` is just always referencing the same instance, which was created when calling `buildList()`.

`var` scope in JavaScript is always bound to current function call, not to code block, so it's not bound to control statements like `for`.

For that reason, the alerts likely show the value `'item' + (list.length-1)` had at the time of calling `buildList()`.

Since you are passing `i` to your closure, you should declare `var item` within that function, e.g:

```
function buildList(list) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        result[i] = function(x) {
            // x and item are both local variables of anonymous function declared just above
            var item = 'item' + list[x]; // or maybe you meant 'item' + x?
            return function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[x])};   
        }(i);
    }
    return result;
```

}

Note that the closure would still capture a reference to `list` so will display the value it contains at the time of calling functions in the array returned by `buildList()`. Also local variable `item` is completely optional, you could call `alert('item' + x /*or is it list[x]?*/ + ' ' + list[x])`.

Answer (score 0):

From [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

> Note that when you run the example, "item2 undefined" is alerted three
>   times! This is because just like previous examples, there is only one
>   closure for the local variables for buildList. When the anonymous
>   functions are called on the line fnlistj; they all use the same
>   single closure, and they use the current value for i and item within
>   that one closure (where i has a value of 3 because the loop had
>   completed, and item has a value of 'item2'). Note we are indexing from
>   0 hence item has a value of item2. And the i++ will increment i to the
>   value 3.

You need to make a closure in each loop iteration if you are to store the matching value of `i`:

```
function buildList(list) {
  var result = [], item, closure;
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    item = 'item' + list[i];

    // call this function with the string you wish to store
    // the inner function will keep a reference to the 'msg' parameter even after the parent function returns
    closure = (function(msg) {
        return function() {
          alert(msg);
        };
      }(item + ' ' + list[i]));
    result.push( closure );
  }
  return result;
}

function testList() {
  var fnlist = buildList([1, 2, 3]);
  // using j only to help prevent confusion - could use i
  for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
    fnlist[j]();
  }
}

testList();
```

Same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933343/how-are-local-variables-referenced-in-closures) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901597/javascript-closure-after-using-anonymous-function). Same answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192348/closures-in-a-for-loop?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803351/javascript-for-loop-index-strangeness?lq=1) and probably in dozen more places.